# What's the amount of time in 足足有一刻钟，简默的脸上现出了惊喜和迷惑?

Tags: translation, time

> 足足有一刻钟，简默的脸上现出了惊喜和迷惑。

It is less than a quarter of an hour, or a full quarter of an hour, or what amount of time is being talked about here?

Answer (score 6):

足足有一刻钟 here means "*a **full** quarter of an hour*".

足足 means *fully*. The word is usually emotional, implying that *that amount is a big deal*. E.g. 我在这里足足等了你两个小时. (implying: two hours is really long time. It's a complaining about the fact that you kept me waiting for that long.)

PS. Compare 足足有两小时 and 足有两个小时. They mean the same(a full two hours), but the former puts an emphasis. 足足 sounds like almost exceeding the amount(or perhaps already exceeds a little bit?).

Answer (score 4):

It means a full quarter of an hour. Besides that, 足足 also have a meaning to describe the duration of the time is very long for the person at speaking. It's like an emphasize. In this sentence, it means the 15 minutes is pretty long for the person who writes this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It is (at least) a full quarter of an hour. Note that [足足](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%B6%B3%E8%B6%B3) is used for emphasizing that.

> ◎ 足足 zúzú
>
> [full;solid] 不少于

Comment: I think "at least" or 不少于 is not accurate because they could imply "over the amount". 足足 would never be over the amount. In English, it should be "fully", "not less than" or "as much as". I think the definition "不少于" in that dictionary is wrong.

Comment: @dan I think it actually means 不少于. if I hear people using 足足, I would expect they're saying "at least"

Comment: @sylvia Do you think they are the same: 足足两碗饭 VS 不少于两碗饭？ In my opinion, 不少于两碗饭 can be 三碗，四碗，五碗，etc. but 足足两碗饭 can never be 三碗, 四碗,... Actually, both terms focus on different aspects.

Comment: @sylvia 足足 denotes the sense of fullness, while 不少于 *no less than*. (I deleted "no less than" in my answer, I found it inappropriate too.)

Comment: @dan i see where you're coming from. I would say 足足两碗饭 is not less than 两碗 but less than 三碗。 It is to express the fullness. 两碗 can be a variety of amount. 足足 is to express these two bowls are very full. If you look at the definition on Baidu Baike 足足 means：1、非常充足。2、状声词。形容雌凤鸣叫的声音。3、指不少于. It also implies that the person actually doesn't know exactly how long, or how full

Comment: @sylvia In this case, online dictionaries are not good source to consult because they are copied around from one another and not well proof read like an official one. I agree that 不少于 can imply that the person doesn't know exactly, but 足足 not. If I have waited you for more than two hours, I would have said: 我足足等了你两个*多*小时, instead of 我足足等了你两个小时. 足足两个小时 only implies a **full** two hours(no more/less than two hours).

Comment: Well, how can you know it's 2 hours not 2 hours 1 second?

Comment: @sylvia I think when someone said 足足两个小时， meaning he is very confident that it has two hours, but he cann't guarantee any longer e.g. 两小时1分. However, the actual time could be possible longer as you suggested "two hours one second". It's one's opinion based, not actual number.

Comment: @sylvia If he is sure it's over two hours, he would most likely to say 足足两个多小时.

Comment: @dan "cann't guarantee any longer" - yes, can't guarantee doesn't mean it's not existed. So 不少于 correct. 不少于 is greater than or equal to - are we on the same page on that? Looks like you agreed with me, but you're stuck on what 不少于 means?

Comment: @sylvia You misunderstand me. Let's say 他们给我足足两桶油. Do you interpret it can be any more than 两桶？We could only imagine they gave me two buckets full of oil(no more than that). It would be different to say 他们给我不少于两桶油， which opens the possibility that they gave me 3, 4, ....

Comment: @sylvia Another example: 你给我的零钱足足两千块 VS 你给我的零钱不少于两千块. They are definitely different.